# What is the best way to load a large amount of items into a <select> tag with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have about 350 items in a .txt file, each on its own line. I want to load that all into a HTML  tag for users to choose from. This would be on a high traffic page on my site, so I don't want to load from the text file every single time.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Load it once and use the rails cache, either caching the HTML fragment or the results of reading the text file.

```
Rails.cache.write( '350itemtextfile', <results of reading the file>)
cached_results = Rails.cache.read('350itemtextfile')
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html